# Linq query to return distinct values in xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML with the following structure:

```
<Categories>
  <Category>
    <Books>
      <Book>
        <BookId>1</BookId>
        <BookQuantity>150</BookQuantity>
      </Book>
      <Book>
        <BookId>2</BookId>
        <BookQuantity>250</BookQuantity>
      </Book>
    </Books>
  </Category>
  <Category>
    <Books>
      <Book>
        <BookId>1</BookId>
        <BookQuantity>150</BookQuantity>
      </Book>
      <Book>
        <BookId>3</BookId>
        <BookQuantity>250</BookQuantity>
      </Book>
    </Books>
  </Category>
</Categories>
```

I am trying to retrieve each distinct Book with its quantity within the category. 
The output would be:

```
Book 1 300
Book 2 250
Book 3 250
```

Any best method to do this. I tried with linq query but was not able to succeed.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take care about formatting. And provide what have you tried so far with specific errors/problems. There is a lot of tutorials about LINQ to XML so it is unlikely that real effort was done...

Comment: Please, add to question query which you tried. That will make your question complete and also we will tell you what exactly went wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Linq to Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx). Query is simple - just select all Book elements and group them by value of BookId element. Then project each group into anonymous object or instance of book class:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);

var books = from b in xdoc.Root.Descendants("Book")
            group b by (int)b.Element("BookId") into g
            select new {
                Id = g.Key,
                Quantity = g.Sum(b => (int)b.Element("BookQuantity"))
            };
```

Result:

```
[
  { "Id": 1, "Quantity": 300 },
  { "Id": 2, "Quantity": 250 },
  { "Id": 3, "Quantity": 250 }
]
```

Instead of creating anonymous objects you can create instances of Book class:

```
public class Book
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why are you answering to the question without any effort presented? Is it going to be portal for writing other people's code? Someone with your reputation should take care about SO quality... If I asked a question "I would like to add two numbers, how to do that?" you would answer to gain easy reputation?!

Comment: Agree with you, I usually skip such questions or mark them with *off-topic because demonstrates minimal understanding of problem being solved*.